# WebSerivce só aceita requisições provenientes de servidor local

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, aplicação-web, http

Tenho um *Webservice* em PHP e preciso usar para integrar duas aplicações. O WS retorna em JSON os dados que preciso. O problema é que ele retorna apenas os dados quando a solicitação é feita a partir de um servidor local. Se eu fizer a *request* a partir de qualquer domínio web ele demora pra caramba para responder e quando responde a resposta vem em branco.

Por exemplo: página busca.php em 127.0.0.1 envia um request para o ws, ele retorna os dados.

página busca.php em teste.com ou qualquer outro domínio web envia um request para o ws ele demora e retorna em branco.

Sabem o que pode ser?

Comment: O Webservice está local, o cliente do webservice está local, ou ambos? E quando usa domínio web está falando do servidor ou do cliente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

veirifique da onde vem a requisição atraves desses codigos   ... nunca falhou comigo ..

```
<?php
        $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

        if ($ip == 'ip do servidor local') {
            mysql_connect('localhost','blabla','senha');
            mysql_select_db('bancodedados') or die (mysql_error());
        }
        elseif ($ip == '127.0.0.1') {
            mysql_connect('localhost','blabla
','senha');
            mysql_select_db('bancodedados') or die (mysql_error());
        }
        else {

            mysql_connect('localweb','root','senha');
            mysql_select_db('bandodedados') or die (mysql_error());

        }
```